# Why can’t we accelerate photons, and is it possible for a photon to have mass?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, acceleration

So I’m doing a science project and I’m trying to understand why the photon is massless. I’ve learned that neutrinos were thought to be massless at first, but then physicists found 3 types of neutrinos and established that they have mass. So what if the photon has mass and there’s 3 different types of photons regarding their type of wave. And can we accelerate the photon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don’t photons interact with the Higgs field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23161/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't photons have a mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/), and of questions linked therein.

Comment: Is not true that you cannot accelerate a photon, at least nominally. The speed of photons in a refractive medium is given by $\frac{c}{n}$, with n the refractive index of the medium. If you build a refractive material with a carefully engineered gradient of the refractive index, you can make light to accelerate or decelerate within it

Comment: There is acceleration as soon as the **velocity vector** change its *orientation*, not just its *norm*.  Thus, when light deviates from the straight path, there is light acceleration.  Gravity alone can induces deviation of light around a massive object.  Light is accelerating in vacuum, in this case (deflexion of rays).