# Why the photon doesn't acquire mass with the Higgs mechanism?

Tags: photons, mass, standard-model, higgs

I did the computation that from 
$$(0,v)^{T}(\partial_\mu+igA_\mu^a\tau^a+i\frac{g'}{2}B_\mu)(\partial_\mu-igA_\mu^b\tau^b-i\frac{g'}{2}B_\mu)(0,v)$$ 
with $(0,v)$ being the expectation value of the Higgs field and $\tau, B_\mu$ being the generator of the SU(2) and U(1) group proves the mass term for the $Z_\mu$ and $W^\pm_\mu$ and not for the photon. That said if I rewrite the covariant derivative  in terms of the $Z_\mu, W^\pm_\mu$ and $A_\mu$ ($c_1,c_2$ being the constant dependent on $e,\theta_\omega$ for brevity):
$$D_\mu=\partial_\mu-c_1[W_\mu^+(\tau^1+i\tau^2)+W_\mu^+(\tau^1-i\tau^2)]-c_2Z_\mu(\tau^3-\sin^2{\theta_\omega}Q)-ieQA_\mu$$
I don't realize how the term in $A_\mu^2$ doesn't give a mass term for the photon. Any hint is well appreciated.

Comment: Part of the confusion is probably that the $A_\mu$ in your first equation is not the same as the $A_\mu$ in your second. They are the gauge fields for $SU(2)_L$ and $U(1)_{EM}$ respectively.

Comment: I know that the two $A$ are not the same and I don't think I confused the square with the index (good tip though)

Comment: The term $e^2Q^2A_\mu^2$ is the problem. I don't understand why it doesn't get mass with the v from the H field

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23161/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is for you to see what the charge operator in your 2×2 matrix notation is when acting on the Higgs doublet, whose upper component is +, and lower component is neutral: of course, the v.e.v. must be chargeless! This is by dint of the [hypercharge 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge) of the (entire) Higgs doublet.

Thus, sandwiching the charge matrix squared  between the Higgs v.e.v.s *(o,v)*  annihilates *Q<sup>2</sup>* and thereby  any feared photon mass term.

More explicitly, ignore the plain derivative, since it collapses on the constant v.e.v., and omit the $W^{\pm}$ in the covariant completion, since they amount to terms orthogonal to the photon and *Z* in the square.

The remnant is the diagonal part of the derivative-completion-squared 2×2 matrix acting on a Higgs doublet, just 
$$
g^2v^2 ~~(0,1) \operatorname{diag}(^3A_\mu +\tan^2\theta_W ~B_\mu, -^3A_\mu +\tan^2\theta_W ~B_\mu  )^2 ~ (0 , 1)^T  \\ 
\equiv \frac{g^2 v^2 }{\cos^2 \theta } (0,1)  \operatorname{diag} (A_\mu ^2, Z_\mu^2) ~(0,1)^T =  \frac{g^2 v^2 }{\cos^2 \theta } Z_\mu^2, 
$$
the calculation you said you had no trouble with.

The very same calculation in the physical (propagating) basis involves
$$
Q=\operatorname{diag} (1,0), \\  \tau^3 - \sin^2\! \theta_W ~Q= \cos^2\! \theta_W \tau^3 -\sin^2\!\theta_W ~ Y/2\\  = 
\operatorname{diag}\!(1/2 -\sin^2\! \theta_W   ,-1/2 ).
$$ 
Acting on the v.e.v., *Q* vanishes, decoupling $A_\mu$ from the uncharged vacuum, as already indicated; while the eigenvalue of the neutral current charge is just -1/2, to be squared to multiply your $c_2^2$, namely $4e^2/(\sin 2\theta_W)^2$, to yield the above mass.