# Do neutrinos have mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos

I'm really curious on this subject and I want to know if neutrinos have mass. I know they are a subatomic particle, but how much mass.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139/ (where I actually answer this question in a different context).

Comment: Yes, neutrinos have mass; you can read the details here: http://ctp.berkeley.edu/neutrino/neutrino.html

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a neutrino has a rest frame, why can't a photon have a rest frame as well?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110968/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can easily be found elsewhere.  No effort shown.

Answer (score 4):

Neutrinos indeed do have mass, we don't know how much mass exactly, but ongoing research have put upper limits of about 0.3 eV [Thanks to  Giorgio Comitini for providing a more accurate value]. Compare with e.g. an electron which has a mass of about $0.5 \times 10^{6} eV $.

We know that neutrinos have mass because ([2015 Nobel Prize!](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2015/)) it has been found that they change from one family to another. There are three neutrino families. This 'oscillation' is only possible if they have mass, and if the mass for each family is different from another's (since they are identical in all other aspects.)

I'd recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino_problem for a not-too-complicated introduction.

Comment: Just to be precise, the least upper bound on the electron neutrino mass as of 2015 seems to have been set at around 0,3 eV (ref. here http://link.aps.org/accepted/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.062502), while research in astrophysics and cosmology (2014, ref. here http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.051303) seem to suggest that 0,3 eV is the least upper bound on the sum of the masses of the three neutrinos.

Comment: Not at all :-).